# Rx.net File watcher

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am new with Rx.net and tried to do a folder watcher that could send a notification when a new file is done being uploaded. Each instance check one and only one folder.

Here are the steps to achieve that:

1. Must check folder content each x Seconds.
2. Clear the "already sent" list of files that are no more in the folder. (If the same file comes back later, we have to send another notification)
3. Check the "already sent" list to prevent sending duplicate notifications.
4. Compare current and previous content (file size, etc) of each files to make sure they are completely uploaded (file size did not change).
5. OpenWrite the new and uploaded files to make sure no one has a lock on it.
6. Add the file to the Already sent list.
7. Send notification.

Most importantly, this code will, hopefully, run for ever and may handle a lot of new files. So I must be sure not to "leak" anything (this is why I clear the "already sent" list in step 2). Also, FileSystemWatcher was my first solution but did not fit my needs.

The code here is doing exactly what I want, but I think it is ugly. I'm sure that there is a way with RX.Net to keep the same logic but in a more readable and efficient way. Can you enlighten me?

```
 private static IObservable<IEnumerable<FileChangedEvent>> CreateWindowsFolderSource(string path)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<FileChangedEvent>>(filesStateObserver =>
        {
            var currentFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").Select(file =>
            {
                long fileLength = 0;
                try
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                    fileLength = fileInfo.Length;
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    //Do not throw if the file was not found. The logic will handle the case where length == 0.
                }

                return new FileChangedEvent(file, fileLength);
            });
            return Observable.Return(currentFiles.ToList()).Subscribe(filesStateObserver.OnNext);
        });
    }


    private static IObservable<FileChangedEvent> ObserveFilesChanges(string path)
    {            
        HashSet<String> alreadySentFiles = new HashSet<String>();
        var timedFolderChangesSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), NewThreadScheduler.Default)
            .SelectMany(_ => CreateWindowsFolderSource(path)); //Step 1)
        return timedFolderChangesSource
                .Zip(timedFolderChangesSource.Skip(1), (prev, cur) => //Make sure we have two snapshots of the files in the folder. (Current and previous) 
                {
                    var currentEvents = cur.ToList();
                    var prevSource = prev.ToObservable();
                    var curSource = currentEvents.ToObservable();
                    alreadySentFiles.IntersectWith(currentEvents.Select(fileEvent => fileEvent.FullPath)); //Step 2)

                    return prevSource.Merge(curSource)
                        .GroupBy(fileEvent => fileEvent.FullPath)
                        .Where(fileUpdates => !alreadySentFiles.Contains(fileUpdates.Key) /*Step 3)*/)
                        .SelectMany(fileEvents =>
                            fileEvents.Zip(fileEvents.Skip(1), (prevEvent, curEvent) => //Make sure we have two events for the same file.
                                new FileChangedEvent(prevEvent.FullPath, curEvent.FileSize, curEvent.FileSize != prevEvent.FileSize))
                            .Where(fileUpdate => !fileUpdate.FileSizeChanged && fileUpdate.FileSize > 0 /*Step 4)*/));
                })
                .Merge()
                .Where(uploadedFile =>
                {
                    bool sendEvent = false;
                    try
                    {
                        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(uploadedFile.FullPath);
                        //Check if the file is not locked anymore.
                        fileInfo.OpenWrite().Dispose(); //Step 5)
                        sendEvent = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //ignore error.. we will retry later
                    }
                    return sendEvent;
                })
                .Do(fileEvent => alreadySentFiles.Add(fileEvent.FullPath) //Step 6) and 7);
    }
```

Comment: Have to taken a look at [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  There's an interesting [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f6c28ce-4ae9-470b-99bc-182e1afa712e/how-to-subscribe-to-observe-events-observablefromevent-in-rx-library-version-1010425-say?forum=rx) question with some examples of hooking it into RX specifically for file system monitoring.

Comment: Hello Dan, Thanks for the answer. As I said in my original post, I already tried File System Watcher, but it is not reliable. Everyone recommend to have a polling mechanism besides the FileSystemWatcher. It is not a good solution for me.

Comment: I have tried using FileSystemWatcher off and on for years and find it's just too unreliable. It seems to work reasonably well on a local drive but is very intermittent on a mapped or network drive. If many changes are made to a network directory the bandwidth is huge. Polling at a reasonable interval seems to be the way to go.